# connection failedAccess denied for user 'arpitara_mitbus'@'gateway' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql

i have created the database in cpanel and imported the database which was there in localhost, but after providing username and passwords and have granted privileges also in the file, it is showing the below error

```
**"connection failedAccess denied for user 'arpitara_mitbus'@'gateway' (using password: YES)"**

 $con=mysqli_connect("bus-routes.mitmysore.in","arpitara_mitbus","mitbus12@","arpitara_3135663_mit");
```

i have included the hostname, username, password and dbname.

Comment: Try to keep your hostname as localhost

Comment: You have to check the permissions in the MySQL server. The MySQL server responded that the application cannot login with the given login credentials. Please [edit] your question to include the content of the `mysql.user` table from your MySQL server.